# How to change CAPSLOCK to CTRL in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, linux-mint

I am running LInux Mint and want to remap CAPSLOCK to CONTROL.

I tried the keyboard setup and I can remap it and all applications work fine EXCEPT Adobe Fireworks. It screws up the combo keys.

So I was wondering if there's another way besides the keyboard preferences. Want to see if there's another method that wont screw up Fireworks when I am running WINE.

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: Tried xmodmap and re-mapped it. But same problem. Fireworks doesnt work normal.

Comment: Got it working a tad better by remapping it to the RIGHT CONTROL..

Comment: this page helped. now at least i can zoom using combo keys in fireworks. but some others still not working. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RemapCapsLock